# Add multiple lines on one graph (series in excel); count responses and average in RStudio

Tags: r, line

I have tried this code:

```
ggplot(data = Master_Data) +
  geom_line(mapping = aes(
    x = fct_inorder(Gate),
    y = c(Correct),
    group = 1),
  stat = 'identity') +
  facet_wrap( ~ Condition, nrow = 2)
```

but it doesn't count and average correct responses for the "Gate"; and I am unable to get two lines (one for AO, one for AV)

Here is the graph that I am trying to replicate from excel to R:
[image]

Here is a small sample of the spreadsheet I uploaded in RStudio:

```
Participant Condition Gate Sound Target Response Correct
VS0005  Clean   POD AV  Baby    baby    1
VS0005  Clean   Gate 1  AV  Sandwich    sandal  0
VS0005  Clean   Gate 2  AV  Rooster ruby    0
VS0005  Clean   Gate 3  AV  Puppy   puppy   1
VS0005  Clean   Full    AV  Peacock pizza   0
VS0005  Clean   POD AO  Banjo   banjo   1
VS0005  Clean   Gate 1  AO  Ferret  fairy   0
VS0005  Clean   Gate 2  AO  Carriage    carrot  0
VS0005  Clean   Gate 3  AO  Marble  marble  1
VS0005  Clean   Full    AO  Pasta   puzzle  0
VS0006  Clean   POD AV  Baby    baby    1
VS0006  Clean   Gate 1  AV  Sandwich    sandal  0
VS0006  Clean   Gate 2  AV  Rooster ruby    0
VS0006  Clean   Gate 3  AV  Puppy   puppy   1
VS0006  Clean   Full    AV  Peacock pizza   0
VS0006  Clean   POD AO  Banjo   banjo   1
VS0006  Clean   Gate 1  AO  Ferret  fairy   0
VS0006  Clean   Gate 2  AO  Carriage    carrot  0
VS0006  Clean   Gate 3  AO  Marble  marble  1
VS0006  Clean   Full    AO  Pasta   puzzle  0
VS0007  Degraded    POD AV  Baby    baby    1
VS0007  Degraded    Gate 1  AV  Sandwich    sandal  0
VS0007  Degraded    Gate 2  AV  Rooster ruby    0
VS0007  Degraded    Gate 3  AV  Puppy   puppy   1
VS0007  Degraded    Full    AV  Peacock pizza   0
VS0007  Degraded    POD AO  Banjo   banjo   1
VS0007  Degraded    Gate 1  AO  Ferret  fairy   0
VS0007  Degraded    Gate 2  AO  Carriage    carrot  0
VS0007  Degraded    Gate 3  AO  Marble  marble  1
VS0007  Degraded    Full    AO  Pasta   puzzle  0
VS0008  Degraded    POD AV  Baby    baby    1
VS0008  Degraded    Gate 1  AV  Sandwich    sandal  0
VS0008  Degraded    Gate 2  AV  Rooster ruby    0
VS0008  Degraded    Gate 1  AV  Puppy   puppy   1
VS0008  Degraded    Full    AV  Peacock pizza   0
VS0008  Degraded    POD AO  Banjo   banjo   1
VS0008  Degraded    Gate 1  AO  Ferret  fairy   0
VS0008  Degraded    Gate 2  AO  Carriage    carrot  0
VS0008  Degraded    Gate 3  AO  Marble  marble  1
VS0008  Degraded    Full    AO  Pasta   puzzle  0
```

Comment: Please don't post photos of the data. It's more helpful if you can provide some of the data using `dput(df)`. Or if you have a lot of data, then you can wrapt it in `head()`, i.e., `dput(head(df))`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I expect something like this should work.

```
library(ggplot2); library(dplyr)
Master_Data %>%
  group_by(Condition, Gate = fct_inorder(Gate), Sound) %>%
  summarize(mean = mean(Correct),
            sd = sd(Correct), .groups = "drop") %>%
  ggplot(aes(x = Gate, y = mean, color = Sound, group = Sound)) +
  geom_line() +
  geom_errorbar(aes(ymin = mean - sd, ymax = mean + sd)) +
  facet_wrap(~Condition) +
  theme_minimal()
```

For the data sample it looks pretty terrible, since most cases only have one observation. Should look a lot more like the excel chart with more data.

[image]